# strange output when I cout an array

Tags: c++

I've never seen anything like this before and I can't figure out what could possibly be causing it.  This is HW so you don't have to fix it for me just give me a clue whats going wrong. Here is my code.

```
void countChars(ifstream& inData, string filename, char x[])
{
for(int i=0; i < 58; i++)
    x[i] = 33+i;

cout << x << endl;
}
```

here is my output

[image: output]

Comment: everything after the Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to null terminate your `char[]`.

`std::cout.operator<<(char*)` uses `\0` to tell where to stop.

This is a duplicate of: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296083/char-array-issue/20296099#20296099)

Comment: thank you. we can't use std:: stuff yet since we haven't learned it but I understand it better now that you explained it that way

Comment: @user2087867 Np, schools / unis can't teach C++, speaking from my own experience. All of the operators are really just function calls.

Answer (score 1):

add a  `x[58] = 0;` before the cout.

Comment: That kind of works but I get an error that says the stack around chararray has been corrupted.

Comment: Yeah, @Richard, this is unsafe advice unless you qualify it by reminding the OP to make sure the array is big enough for an extra `char`. You've just taught the OP to write a buffer overrun into his code.