# string to character conversion error?

Tags: c++

After trying for about 1 hour, my code didn't work because of this:

```
void s_s(string const& s, char data[10])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        data[i] = s[i];
}

int main()
{
    string ss = "1234567890";
    char data[10];
    s_s("1234567890", data);

    cout << data << endl;//why junk
}
```

I simply don't understand why the cout displays junk after the char array. Can someone please explain why and how to solve it?

Comment: Please include the output. Does it print '1234567890' and then junk, or only junk? `cout` prints everything up to the '\0' character, which is not present in your `data` array; thus it might print additional junk between '1234567890' and the next `\0` it bumps into in the memory.

Comment: it does printadditional junk after 0.

Comment: There you go. Also, did you mean to write `s_s(ss, data);` in the 3rd line of your `main`? otherwise the `ss` string is useless. And, you send a `const char` to your `s_s` function, which actually expects to receive a const string reference....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to null terminate your char array.
`std::cout.operator<<(char*)` uses `\0` to know where to stop.
Your `char[]` decays to `char*` by the way.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268769/why-do-i-get-garbage-value-when-output-character-array-to-console/20268786#20268786).

Comment: my array is 10 characters. i need to make it 11, so i can hold this null terminating thing?

Comment: if i use this array only for comparisons, do i still need to make it 11 characters?

Comment: @SkyRipper No, you iterate exactly 10 times as you can see.

Comment: @SkyRipper However, when printing, it keeps printing forever untill it finds `\0`.

Comment: @SkyRipper Yes, do make sure you make enough room. Or, alternatively, simply use std::string for everything :).

Comment: @SkyRipper No, it is not slow AT ALL, trust me.

Comment: i am not sure about speed, but takes at least 2x ram. when you allocate 1m string, you have to ram to waste

Comment: This will fail, he does not have space to add the '\0' in data[10]

Comment: @SkyRipper Not really, there's just a small handle for std::string, when you allocate a larger string, you will barely notice any difference.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum 1) read my answer again 2) look at the comments

Comment: Your answer needs to refelect the need to increase the buffer, not the comments.  And the answer needs to state that it will fail, as opposed to it being a nice to have

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum No it doesn't, my answer needs to contain whatever I deem necessary to answer a particular question and provide a solution for a particular problem.

Comment: True, you can reserve the right to leave a bad or incomplete answer

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned you want to NUL terminate your array, but here's something else to consider:

If `s` is your source string, then you want to loop to `s.size()`, so that you don't loop past the size of your source string.

```
void s_s(std::string const& s, char data[20])
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        data[i] = s[i];
    data[s.size()] = '\0';
}
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
std::copy(ss.begin(), ss.begin()+ss.size(),
  data);
data[ss.size()] = '\0';

std::cout << data << std::endl;
```

Comment: @SkyRipper The first one is probably faster (don't take my word for it), but the second one is practically a one-liner.

Comment: This will fail, he does not have space to add the '\0' in data[10]

Comment: @Glenn Yeah, I changed it to `20`, although it is implied that he will change the buffer size.

Answer (score 2):

You have ONLY allocated 10 bytes for data

The string is actually 11 bytes since there is an implied `'\0'` at the end

At a minimum you should increase the size of data to 11, and change your loop to copy the `'\0'` as well

Comment: if I don't do this, what I lose, expect I can't print it?

Comment: If you attempt to add an 11th char - `\0` at the end then you hit undefined behaviour and your code can crash

Comment: Yes, but if i never print the char array, is there a reason to add /0?

Comment: @SkyRipper - how do you know where it ends without a `'\0`'` to tell you it ends.   This called a sentinel value if you want to look into more depth

Answer (score 0):

The function [`std::ostream::operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that you are trying to use in the last line of the main will take your `char` array as a pointer and will print every `char` until the *null sentinel* character is found (the character is `\0`).

This sentinel character is generally generated for you in statements where a C-string literal is defined:

```
char s[] = "123";
```

In the above example `sizeof(s)` is `4` because the actual characters stored are:

```
'1', '2', '3', '\0'
```

The last character is fundamental in tasks that require to loop on every char of a `const char*` string, because the condition for the loop to terminate, is that the `\0` must be read.

In your example the "junk" that you see are the bytes following the `0` char byte in the memory (interpreted as `char`). This behavior is clearly undefined and can potentially lead the program to crash.

One solution is to obviously add the `\0` char at the end of the char array (of course fixing the size).

The best solution, though, is to never use `const char*` for strings at all. You are correctly using `std::string` in your example, which will prevent this kind of problems and many others.

If you ever need a `const char*` (for C APIs for example) you can always use [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) and retrieve the C string version of the `std::string`.

Your example could be rewritten to:

```
int main(int, char*[]) {
    std::string ss = "1234567890";
    const char* data = ss.c_str();
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}
```

(in this particular instance, a version of `std::ostream::operator<<` that takes a `std::string` is already defined, so you don't even need `data` at all)